# Customizing fullpage.js to skip section(s) dynamically

Tags: toggle, fullpage.js

The question is simple but i'm not able to make a script by myself for what i need...
I am actually using a script ( fullpage.js ) who toggle some classes into a container ( in my case switching from fp-viewing-1 to fp-viewing-x ) when you scroll down/up between sections.
I need to make a script that listen from this container and toggle a new class into a div ONLY when a class ( in my case fp-viewing-3 ) is added to this container ( from the fullpage.js script of course ).

Any way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to my problem.
Fullpage works as intended except for section 2.
Section 2 will be usable only scrolling down, the script ignore it when scrolling up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#application').fullpage({

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var destinationToIgnore = $('.fp-section').hasClass('ignore');

        if(destinationToIgnore && direction =='up'){
            var destination = nextIndex = 1
            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(destination);

        }
    },


    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        if(index !== 1){
         $('.section-intro').removeClass('ignore');            
        }
        if(index == 3){
         $('.section-intro').addClass('ignore');            
        }

    }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make a script that listen from this container

That's not the way to go for it.

**If you want to use the status class**, then just create a new class based on the previous ones as explained [in this fullpage.js tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Create a conditional CSS class that will only get applied when its parent class matches your requirement.

Something like this, for example, would only apply the `red` color to element with `myClass` when you are in section 1 slide 0.

```
.fp-viewing-1-0 .myClass{
    color: red;
}
```

Having:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section myClass"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
<div>
```

**If for some other reason (use of plugins etc) you really need to add the class dynamically**, then go for fullpage.js callbacks `onLeave` or `afterLoad`:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var destination = $('.section').eq(nextIndex - 1);
        destination.find('.my-element').addClass('myClass');            
    }
});
```

Comment: the script ( i edited first post ) works but not as intended. When i scroll up from index-3 i have to repeat the scroll action more and more times to get it working. Do you know why ?

Comment: I've already answer your question. If you have other problem you should create another question.

Comment: ?
the plugin doesn't work as intended with my script... it removes/add correctly the class .ignore and in the same way it skips the .ignore section BUT when scrolling up from the section next to the ignored one it just doesn't work, it doesn't scroll up (actually it does but after 10-20 attempts).
Shall i make a video of my problem? I don't know if it's clear enough :\

Comment: Nop, add an isolated reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen.